# List of possible Status outputs from Get-AzureVM

Tags: powershell, azure

I have been unable to find a list of the possible states can be returned for Status from Get-AzureVM.

For example, I am currently checking:

1) `$VMs = Get-AzureVM | where {$_.Status -eq "ReadyRole"}`

2) `$VMs = Get-AzureVM | where {$_.Status -eq "StoppedDeallocated"}`

3) `$VMs = Get-AzureVM | where {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}`

Are there any other possible outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see all the possible values, you can get this information from Service Management API documentation page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx. Scroll down to section `RoleInstanceList` and you will see all possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you are missing some possible outputs- **RoleStateUnknown, CreatingVM, Provisioning, ProvisioningTimeout**.  Screenshot for your reference- [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks Aatif, but if you go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx like Guarav said, you'll see there are even more status's than your 4.

Comment: Gaurav has the best answer for this question.